# How to customise react-final-form record and field validation?

Tags: validation, react-final-form, final-form

There is a few question I wish to ask about react-final-form.

1. How can I prevent form auto call validate on form init? I try to have a work around to skip it by check if form is dirty or pristine and it resume its original behavior once a field is changed. The problem is I not able to get the meta in record validation.

   ```
   <Form 
     validate={value => {
       const errors = {};
       // if (!meta.dirty) return errors;
       ... continue validation
     }
     render={}
    />
   ```
2. How can I programmatic call form/record level validate without touching any field?
3. Instead of record level validation, I have field level validate with validateFields and for each field to prevent full validation (I have a lot of AJAX call for each field validation) when only 1 field change. But I need to fire all field validation when I click submit button. Is there a way to fire all field validation at once?

Comment: Similarly, I'd like to be able to skip validation when clicking a "cancel" button.